# Using Customizer to define category_name in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am trying to use the Wordpress Customizer to allow the client to input the category names for post that will appear on the homepage. The design calls for two columns of posts, with definable categories for each column.

My hope is that I could do something like:

```
if( get_theme_mod( 'column_1_category') != "" ); 

$args = array(
'category_name' => echo get_theme_mod( 'column_1_category'); ),
'posts_per_page' => 2
);
```

I have already defined the column_1_category in customizer.php, and it works great by itself, but I would like whatever category is typed into the customizer to define the category_name in the $args = array( code.

The 'category_name' = > echo . .  is the line that keeps giving me errors. I am assume, if this even works, that I am missing some code in there?

I was hoping this would be a quick and easy way to define the Category, but not sure if this would even work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i figured it out. All I needed to do was:

```
$category_2_name = get_theme_mod( 'column_2_content');

$args = array(
'category_name' => ($category_2_name),
'posts_per_page' => 2
);
```